# How to Create Short Code Using Custom Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, shortcode

I am New To Wordpress Plugin Development. I want to Create  Short Code using Custom Post Type Method

```
function baztag_func( $atts, $content = "" ) {
    return "content = $content";
}
add_shortcode( 'baztag', 'baztag_func' );
```

Comment: Sorry! But not getting you. What exactly want you ?

Comment: [contact-form-7 id="11" title="Contact form 1"]

Comment: create short code like this

Comment: but i want use cusome post type

Comment: You want custom post type posts listing ,using shortcode right ?

Comment: @PratikPatel   yes correct

Comment: I have added answer so please check and let me know if any query.

Comment: please let me know its working or not for you ?

Comment: sure I will be inform

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    /**
     * Register all shortcodes
     *
     * @return null
     */
    function register_shortcodes() {
        add_shortcode( 'listing', 'shortcode_mostra_produtos' );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes' );

    /**
     * Produtos Shortcode Callback
     * 
     * @param Array $atts
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function shortcode_mostra_produtos( $atts ) {
        global $wp_query,
            $post;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'type' => ''
        ), $atts );

        $loop = new WP_Query( array(
            'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
            'post_type'         => $atts['type']
        ) );

        if( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
            return false;
        }

        while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            $loop->the_post();
            echo the_title();
// DO YOUR HTML STUFF HERE
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

Use short-code like:

> [listing type="YOUR CUSTOM POST TYPE HERE"]

Please try and let me know if any query

Thanks!